# Attached garage with sub panel not wired correctly, needs upgrade

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

200 amp service, 30 amp breaker from main to the garage sub panel, which is 97 feet run. The conductor is 12/2, in the sub panel has two 20 amp breakers and three 15 amp. I want to upgrade to 200 amps, I am going to install an electric garage heater that requires a 60 amp breaker. I have an upright freezer, power tools, 2 garage door openers, TV, stereo, and will add an air compressor. Also, want to feed shed in the future. I have researched the wire from 250/250/250 3/0 would this be a good choice? I am concerned about the thickness and it fitting into the lugs of the sub panel. Currently, I flip the garage breaker if I run a 1500 watt block heater, 1500 watt dog hair dryer, and the freezer. Only 2 of the 3 can be on at any given time. The house was built in 2010.
Oh yeah, I other thing lights flicker/dim when something turns on that requires a large starting load and then return to normal.

Comment: First you need a load calculation for your 200 amp service.  If you want 200 amps for the garage you probably want a separate service or upgrade to 400 amps.  A heat pump will probably be better at heating per cost to run or most other heating types compared to electric heat.

Comment: 200A is **way** overkill unless you plan to install a big tankless electric water heater (*don't do that*.) And as crip659 said: **load calculation** first.And as crip659 *also* said **heat pump**. Figure all that out before jumping to 200A (and a likely service upgrade). My hunch is that 100A will be more than enough, and that means much smaller (cheaper!) wire and easier in a bunch of ways. Also: Need ground rods. **And what you have right now using 12 AWG for 30A is totally 100% not code-compliant.** You are fortunate the breaker has been tripping instead of burning the place down.

Comment: A 20A heat pump will cost you **a lot less over time** for the same heat as a 60A resistance heater, though it **will cost more** to purchase/install. It will pay for itself if you're not flipping the house. Plus, you get AC. As for fitting wires on the sub-panel, you're going to upgrade that to 200A, so it should be no problem.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Does OP need ground rods for an attached garage?  They are needed for a detach garage.

Comment: For a bunch of reasons, first and foremost: **97 feet run**, I am reasonably certain this is a detached garage, in which case clearly needs ground rods.

Comment: @crip659 Except now I realized the *title* says attached. 97 feet? Really?

Comment: Based on "attached" in the title, I am closing with a same-building subpanel post as duplicate. If that doesn't cover things well enough **or if it is detached**, add more details and it can be reopened.

Comment: 1/0 aluminum, it is 120A wire.